# query regarding writing in a file using c

Tags: c, file-handling

Assume that the files are `.txt`

Contents of first file

> hello how are you

Contents of second file

> I am fine

The desired result is

> hello how are you I am fine

Normally what happens is that the original contents are removed and then new contents are added in it.

I want to write in the first file in such a way that its original contents are maintained and the contents of second file are concatenated in it.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Yes, you can open the file for appending and start writing at the end. Use the [fseek](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek) function to move position in the file.

Comment: Have a look at some of the open flags for fopen, one should let you append to a file when writing to it.

Comment: The [`fopen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) function have other modes than just open for plain reading or writing.

Comment: Write some code and do the exercise for the homework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can append another string in file by opening it in appending mode.

```
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen("file.txt","a");
```

here the next string will append after the last pointer of file.For more info [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fopen.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can open the file with:

`fopen("fileName", "a");`

This will let you append to the end if the file.
More info is here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/

Answer (score 1):

It would help to know how you are trying to write the file.  Likely, you are looking for the append option to FOPEN:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/

```
FILE *f = fopen("foo.txt","a");
if (f != NULL) {
  /* Use f */
  fclose(f);
}
```